# Creating a custom node in a D3 force graph with drag, zoom and pan enabled

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, graph

I'm trying to use the library D3 in my React web application to create a graph to display some information.
I was able to configure all the features I wanted (ex. drag, zoom, pan). **The last thing I need to do is to customize the node element**, so that instead of a circle, **I have an element showing more information**. I've found multiple example on the internet, but when I try to insert it with my code it never works.

I've recreated a small example with just this issue within jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/x8e39j2m/12/, basically **I need the element at the bottom of the page to be used for each node of the graph** (atm the nodes are simple circles)

Below the example of the graph I'm able to create now and on the lower left the template I would like to use for each node.
[image: example graph I have now]

For reference, here is the code:

```
const ForceGraph = () => {

        const data = {
        name: "CEO",
      color: "#123",
      other_details: "test",
      url: "https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/01/43/42/83/360_F_143428338_gcxw3Jcd0tJpkvvb53pfEztwtU9sxsgT.jpg",
            children: [{
        name: "Manager 1",
      color: "#312",
      other_details: "test2",
      url: "https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/01/43/42/83/360_F_143428338_gcxw3Jcd0tJpkvvb53pfEztwtU9sxsgT.jpg",
            children: [{
        name: "Client 1",
      color: "#a41",
      other_details: "test4",
      url: "https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/01/43/42/83/360_F_143428338_gcxw3Jcd0tJpkvvb53pfEztwtU9sxsgT.jpg",
            children: []
    },{
        name: "Client 2",
      color: "#943",
      other_details: "test5",
      url: "https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/01/43/42/83/360_F_143428338_gcxw3Jcd0tJpkvvb53pfEztwtU9sxsgT.jpg",
            children: []
    }]
    },{
        name: "Manager 2",
      color: "#a41",
      other_details: "test3",
      url: "https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/01/43/42/83/360_F_143428338_gcxw3Jcd0tJpkvvb53pfEztwtU9sxsgT.jpg",
            children: [{
        name: "Client 3",
      color: "#921",
      other_details: "test6",
      url: "https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/01/43/42/83/360_F_143428338_gcxw3Jcd0tJpkvvb53pfEztwtU9sxsgT.jpg",
            children: []
    }]
    }
    ]
    }

    const svgRef = React.useRef(null);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        // Specify the chart’s dimensions.
        const width = 928;
        const height = 200;

        const drag = simulation => {

            function dragstarted(event, d) {
                if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
                d.fx = d.x;
                d.fy = d.y;
            }

            function dragged(event, d) {
                d.fx = event.x;
                d.fy = event.y;
            }

            function dragended(event, d) {
                if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
                d.fx = null;
                d.fy = null;
            }

            return d3.drag()
                .on("start", dragstarted)
                .on("drag", dragged)
                .on("end", dragended);
        }

        // Compute the graph and start the force simulation.
        const root = d3.hierarchy(data);
        const links = root.links();
        const nodes = root.descendants();

        const simulation = d3.forceSimulation(nodes)
            .force("link", d3.forceLink(links).id(d => d.id).distance(0).strength(1))
            .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-50))
            .force("x", d3.forceX())
            .force("y", d3.forceY());

        // Clear old graph
        const svg = d3.select(svgRef.current);
        svg.selectAll('*').remove();
        svg.attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .attr("viewBox", [-width / 2, -height / 2, width, height])
            .attr("style", "max-width: 100%; height: auto;")
            .attr("border", "1px solid red");

        // Append links.
        const link = svg.append("g")
            .attr("stroke", "#999")
            .attr("stroke-opacity", 0.6)
            .selectAll("line")
            .data(links)
            .join("line");

        // Append nodes.
        const node = svg.append("g")
            .attr("fill", "#fff")
            .attr("stroke", "#000")
            .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
            .selectAll("circle")
            .data(nodes)
            .join("circle")
            .attr("fill", d => d.children ? null : "#000")
            .attr("stroke", d => d.children ? null : "#fff")
            .attr("r", 3.5)
            .call(drag(simulation));

        node.append("title")
            .text(d => d.data.name);

        simulation.on("tick", () => {
            link
                .attr("x1", d => d.source.x)
                .attr("y1", d => d.source.y)
                .attr("x2", d => d.target.x)
                .attr("y2", d => d.target.y);
            node
                .attr("cx", d => d.x)
                .attr("cy", d => d.y);
        });

        const zoom = d3.zoom()
            .scaleExtent([0.1, 5]) // Set the zoom scale limits
            .on('zoom', (event) => {
                svg.selectAll('*')
                    .attr('transform', event.transform);
            });

        // Apply zoom behavior to the SVG element
        svg.call(zoom);

        return () => simulation.stop();
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            <div style={{"border": "1px solid red"}}>
          <svg ref={svgRef}></svg>
            </div>
        
        <div style={{"margin": "10px", "display": "flex", "align-items": "center"}}>
          <img style={{"border-radius": "50%", "height":"30px", "width": "30px", "border": "1px solid red"}} src="https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/01/43/42/83/360_F_143428338_gcxw3Jcd0tJpkvvb53pfEztwtU9sxsgT.jpg"/>
          <div style={{"display": "flex", "flex-direction": "column", "marginLeft":"5px"}}>
            <div style={{"font-size": "18px", "font-weight": "bold"}}>CEO</div>
            <div style={{"font-size": "13px"}}>Other info</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<ForceGraph />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

and here is part of the CSS:

```
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  height: 600px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to get rid of the circle and to create a foreignObject like so:
https://jsfiddle.net/7bf4s3ap/41/

```
const ForceGraph = () => {

        const data = {
        name: "CEO",
      color: "#123",
      other_details: "test",
      url: "https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/01/43/42/83/360_F_143428338_gcxw3Jcd0tJpkvvb53pfEztwtU9sxsgT.jpg",
            children: [{
        name: "Manager 1",
      color: "#312",
      other_details: "test2",
      url: "https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/01/43/42/83/360_F_143428338_gcxw3Jcd0tJpkvvb53pfEztwtU9sxsgT.jpg",
            children: [{
        name: "Client 1",
      color: "#a41",
      other_details: "test4",
      url: "https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/01/43/42/83/360_F_143428338_gcxw3Jcd0tJpkvvb53pfEztwtU9sxsgT.jpg",
            children: []
    },{
        name: "Client 2",
      color: "#943",
      other_details: "test5",
      url: "https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/01/43/42/83/360_F_143428338_gcxw3Jcd0tJpkvvb53pfEztwtU9sxsgT.jpg",
            children: []
    }]
    },{
        name: "Manager 2",
      color: "#a41",
      other_details: "test3",
      url: "https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/01/43/42/83/360_F_143428338_gcxw3Jcd0tJpkvvb53pfEztwtU9sxsgT.jpg",
            children: [{
        name: "Client 3",
      color: "#921",
      other_details: "test6",
      url: "https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/01/43/42/83/360_F_143428338_gcxw3Jcd0tJpkvvb53pfEztwtU9sxsgT.jpg",
            children: []
    }]
    }
    ]
    }

    const svgRef = React.useRef(null);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        // Specify the chart’s dimensions.
        const width = 928;
        const height = 200;

        const drag = simulation => {

            function dragstarted(event, d) {
                if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
                d.fx = d.x;
                d.fy = d.y;
            }

            function dragged(event, d) {
                d.fx = event.x;
                d.fy = event.y;
            }

            function dragended(event, d) {
                if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
                d.fx = null;
                d.fy = null;
            }

            return d3.drag()
                .on("start", dragstarted)
                .on("drag", dragged)
                .on("end", dragended);
        }

        // Compute the graph and start the force simulation.
        const root = d3.hierarchy(data);
        const links = root.links();
        const nodes = root.descendants();

        const simulation = d3.forceSimulation(nodes)
            .force("link", d3.forceLink(links).id(d => d.id).distance(500).strength(2))
            .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-500))
            .force("x", d3.forceX())
            .force("y", d3.forceY());

        // Clear old graph
        const svg = d3.select(svgRef.current);
        svg.selectAll('*').remove();
        svg.attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .attr("viewBox", [-width / 2, -height / 2, width, height])
            .attr("style", "max-width: 100%; height: auto;")
            .attr("border", "1px solid red");

        // Append links.
        const link = svg.append("g")
            .attr("stroke", "#999")
            .attr("stroke-opacity", 0.6)
            .selectAll("line")
            .data(links)
            .join("line");

        /*/ Append nodes.
        const nodeParent = svg.append("g")
            .attr("fill", "#fff")
            .attr("stroke", "#000")
            .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
            
        const node = nodeParent.selectAll("circle")
            .data(nodes)
            .join("circle")
            .attr("fill", d => d.children ? null : "#000")
            .attr("stroke", d => d.children ? null : "#fff")
            .attr("r", 3.5)
            .call(drag(simulation));

        node.append("title")
            .text(d => d.data.name);*/
            
            const nodeParent = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "node-group")
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("g")
    .call(drag(simulation));
/*
// Append circles for visualization.
const node = nodeParent.append("circle")
    .attr("fill", d => d.children ? null : "#000")
    .attr("stroke", d => d.children ? null : "#fff")
    .attr("r", 25);*/
            
        // Append a div for each node.
const nodeDiv = nodeParent.append("foreignObject")
    .attr("width", 100) // Set the width of the div
    .attr("height", 50); // Set the height of the div

// Append HTML elements (e.g., headings, paragraphs) to the div.
nodeDiv.append("xhtml:div")
    .html(d => `
            <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row">
            <div style="display: flex;">
            <img src="${d.data.url}" style="width: 40px; height: 40px; border-radius: 50%; border: 2px solid red" />
          </div>
          <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; margin-left: 5px;">
            <div style="font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold">CEO</div>
            <div style="font-size: 13px">Other info</div>
          </div>
        </div>
    `);

        simulation.on("tick", () => {
            link
                .attr("x1", d => d.source.x)
                .attr("y1", d => d.source.y)
                .attr("x2", d => d.target.x)
                .attr("y2", d => d.target.y);
            /*node
                .attr("cx", d => d.x)
                .attr("cy", d => d.y);*/
            nodeDiv
                .attr("x", d => d.x)
                .attr("y", d => d.y-25);
        });

        const zoom = d3.zoom()
            .scaleExtent([0.1, 5]) // Set the zoom scale limits
            .on('zoom', (event) => {
                link.attr("transform", event.transform);
              //node.attr("transform", event.transform);
              nodeDiv.attr("transform", event.transform);
            });

        // Apply zoom behavior to the SVG element
        svg.call(zoom);

        return () => simulation.stop();
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            <div style={{"border": "1px solid red"}}>
          <svg ref={svgRef}></svg>
            </div>
        
        <div style={{"margin": "10px", "display": "flex", "align-items": "center"}}>
          <img style={{"border-radius": "50%", "height":"30px", "width": "30px", "border": "1px solid red"}} src="https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/01/43/42/83/360_F_143428338_gcxw3Jcd0tJpkvvb53pfEztwtU9sxsgT.jpg"/>
          <div style={{"display": "flex", "flex-direction": "column", "marginLeft":"5px"}}>
            <div style={{"font-size": "18px", "font-weight": "bold"}}>CEO</div>
            <div style={{"font-size": "13px"}}>Other info</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<ForceGraph />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```